# BitmapFactory.Options

Tags: android, bitmap

Recently, I'm learning how to load bitmap in android efficiantly based on  android [Android Training](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html). I encountered a problem. Here is my code:

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.f, options);
    Log.i("TOM", "resource bitmap dimension: " + options.outWidth + " X " + options.outHeight);

    options.inSampleSize = 8;
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.f, options);
    Log.i("TOM", "require bitmap dimension: " + options.outWidth + " X " + options.outHeight);
```

These code prints:

```
resource bitmap dimension: 1365 X 2048
require bitmap dimension: 342 X 512
```

After I set inSampleSize into `8`, `width` and `height` become `1/8` of the origin dimension as [Android Training](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) said. But `512` is `1/4` of `2048`!
Why?

Comment: why didn't you check the side of `bm` instead of using `option`?

Comment: Thanks! I check the side of `bm`. The result is the same: `342 X 512`!

Comment: And I found If I did not change `inJustDecodeBounds`  into `false` after I set `inSampleSize`, result was  `171 X 256`. I was confused!